# Android Emulator ultra slow on Linux

Tags: android, linux, performance, emulation, tablet

Yet another "slow emulator!" thread, but not quite. Ussualy people are complaining about boot time - for me it doesn't matter and I have snapshot option enabled. The problem with my emulator is that GUI is very unresponsive - by that I mean I have to wait around 3-4 seconds for emulator to register my click on a button for example. Since I don't have a physical device I am forced to work with this emulator.

The device I am emulating is Galaxy Tab 2 10.1, which means WXGA800 and large resolution (800x1280). I've set the device RAM size to 1024.

I am running Linux - if it makes any difference (because of crappy Graphics driver).

So what can I do to make it a bit more responsive? I can live with up to 1sec delay but not more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the new x86 Emulators from Google.

> http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2012/04/faster-emulator-with-better-hardware.html

Comment: This looks really promising. However, how to download? Couldn't find it anywhere officialy.

Comment: Open the Android SDK Manager > Browse to 2.3.3 or 4.0.3 > Download x86 Atom System Image.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any good solution for your problem but you can try to use Android on Virtualbox. Here you have site with .iso files:

```
http://www.android-x86.org/download
```

Comment: I would prefer Leandros solution. Still, thanks for participating.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to emulate devices using a Virtual Machine. I did a detailed tutorial (step by step) based in other tutorials:

http://edwindh.blogspot.com/2014/07/emular-uma-tablet-ou-smartphone-com.html